# Calling webservice in ksoap2

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I've got a problem with this webservice. I used to call diffrent ws in my project and it works fine.

```
private static final String URL2 = "http://46.248.168.51/webservice/soap/endpoint/apikey/cb7f1f308e82ca2be8541d5ba829dc1e/?wsdl";
        private static final String METHOD_NAME2 = "getObjectList";
        private static final String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http://46.248.168.51/webservice/soap/endpoint/apikey/cb7f1f308e82ca2be8541d5ba829dc1e/getObjectList";
        private static final String NAMESPACE2 = "http://46.248.168.51/webservice/soap/endpoint/apikey/cb7f1f308e82ca2be8541d5ba829dc1e/";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.pp);

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE2, METHOD_NAME2);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL2);

            httpTransport.debug = true;

            try {
                httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION2, envelope);

                SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("e.getMessage()", e.getMessage());
                e.getMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**httpTransport.call returns errors**

11-10 15:31:43.421: D/e.getMessage()(2550): expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG @2:486 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4124e8d0)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Looks like the webservice doesn't return a response that conforms to SOAP.

Comment: Make sure the webservice is returning a soap object in response.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code works with several other web services. I think you have only changed the URL,SOAP Action and Method. So please check weather the response contain a popper SOAP message. To check that you can something like TCPMon in between the communication.